# Placement of @Autowired annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, pojo

I've seen the @Autowired annotation placed just before the constructor of a POJO used as controller.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController{

    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @Autowired
    public void LoginController(UsuarioService usuarioService){
        this.usuarioService = usuarioService;
    }

    // More code
}
```

This constructor takes as argument the reference to the object we want Spring to inject.However if I place this annotation just before the property declaration the application works just the same.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController{

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    // More code
}
```

My question is what is the difference between this two approaches in terms of pros and cons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice to you would be to never use `@Autowired` on fields (except in Spring @Configuration classes).

The reason is very simple: TESTING!!!!

When you use `@Autowired` on fields of a class, then that class becomes harder to unit test because you cannot easily use your own (possible mocked) dependencies for the class under test. 
When you use constructor injection then is becomes immediately evident what the dependencies of the class are, and creating that class becomes straight forward (simple constructor call).

Some points that need to made:

1) Some might argue that even when `@Autowired` is used the class can still be unit tested with the use of Mockito's `@InjectMocks`, or Spring's `ReflectionTestUtils.setField`, but my opinion is that the creation of a unit under test should be as dead simple as possible.

2) Another point that could be mentioned is that there might be many arguments in the constructor making the manual invocation of the constructor (either in the test or elsewhere) difficult. This however is not a problem regarding  the creation of the class, but a problem in the design. When a class has to many dependencies, in most cases it is trying to do [too much](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) and needs to broken into smaller classes with fewer dependencies.

Comment: Ditto on these comments - autowired should only appear in a @Configuration annotated class!

Answer (score 0):

**`@Autowired` annotation on setter methods** is to get rid of the  element in XML configuration file. When Spring finds an @Autowired annotation used with setter methods, it tries to perform byType autowiring on the method

**`@Autowired` annotation on properties** is to get rid of the setter methods. When you will pass values of autowired properties using  Spring will automatically assign those properties with the passed values or references.

Here is an example of both the usage:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_autowired_annotation.htm

Comment: for testibility, I would advise against putting the Autowired injection by field as "private". You cannot set the value using JUnit. Either use constructor based injection or use default scope field injection for Autowired.

Answer (score 0):

This [Springsource blog post](http://spring.io/blog/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required) mentions that constructor injection makes it easy to validate required dependencies, if used in combination with contructors assertions that are good practice anyway and would also work if the class is instantiated outside Spring with the new operator:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController{

    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @Autowired
    public void LoginController(UsuarioService usuarioService){
        if (usuarioService == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("usuarioService cannot be null.");
        }
        this.usuarioService = usuarioService;
    }
}
```

This type of assertions are general best practice that is advised to do independently of the class being a Spring bean or not.

For setter or property injection there is also the `@Required` annotation for validating missing dependencies or `@Autowired(required = true)`. According to the blog post, constructor injection provides this advantage, but for historical reasons setter injection is more frequently used in Spring.